# Nature of closest('') selector

Tags: jquery

I am doing some experiment with JQuery and this happen,

There is a check box and if user click it, then`<p>` tag going to append in closest div and also if user unclick it the `<p>` tag going to be removed.

When I do `$(obj).closest("div").append` the paragraph going to append in next closest div, but when I unclick it it removed the whole div. I don't want to look into removing the child div rather, when I am doing `$(obj).closest("div").append` I does not append on same div but next div, when I remove it also remove the whole checkbox div. can anyone explain?

```
$("#checkObxId").click(function() {
var result = onCheckChange(this);
addDynamicRow(this, result);
});

function onCheckChange(obj) {
$(obj).val(false);
var result = false;
if ($(obj).prop("checked") == true) {
    $(obj).val(true);
    result = true;
}
return result;
}

function addDynamicRow(obj, result) {
if (result) {
    $(obj).closest("div").append("<p>This is input</p>");
} else {
    $(obj).closest("div").empty();
  } 
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="smsForm">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToOrganization"
        id="smsToOrganization"> SMS TO Organization
    </label>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToClient"
        id="smsToClient">Sms To Clien
    </label>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToBod" id="smsToBod">
        Sms To BOD
    </label>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToAnyone"
        id="smsToAnyone"> SMS To Anyone
    </label>
   </div>
  <div></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `$.parents()` instead of `$.closest()`.

[image: See more for complete docs]

Comment: thank you, @Arvind , i am interested in why it append the content to next closest div and why it remove the previous div also, i am not much familiar with js , something i am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).closest("div").append("<p id='test'>This is input</p>"); //append id="test" nearest code...
        } else {
            $('#test').remove(); //remove id="test" closest code...
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToOrganization"
        id="smsToOrganization"> SMS TO Organization
    </label>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToClient"
        id="smsToClient">Sms To Clien
    </label>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToBod" id="smsToBod">
        Sms To BOD
    </label>
</div>
<div></div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label> <input type="checkbox" name="smsToAnyone"
        id="smsToAnyone"> SMS To Anyone
    </label>
   </div>
  <div></div>
```

> Note:-
>   You need to give give appended id the name so..we can remove by its id name....

Comment: this is right , thanks , any idea my code remove the parent element?

Comment: please share your code...so can help you what you want...?